# How to set major mode localleader keybinding to both `SPC m` and `comma` in Doom

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode, doom

I want to be able to use both `SPC m` and `,` as major mode localleader keybinding in Doom. With my current Doom setup, I can only use `,` as localleader key. `SPC m` is undefined currently.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my [doom config](https://codeberg.org/haditim/.doom.d)

```lisp
(setq doom-localleader-key ",")

;; Also use SPC m for localleader
(defun my/call-localleader ()
  (interactive)
  (setq unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence ",")))

(map! :leader (:desc "localleader" "m" #'my/call-localleader))
```

This is a hack, but I could not find any better solution to it.

Comment: Thanks! It works great for me!